# Unusual parameterization of the ring Dupin cyclide

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

I discovered the following by playing with the formulas given in the paper [Sculptures in $S^3$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.4952) by Schleimer and Segerman.

First, define the following parameterization of the Clifford torus:
$$
p(\theta, \phi) = \begin{pmatrix}
    \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\ \cos(\theta)\sin(\phi) \\ 
    \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\ \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now, define
$$
n(\theta, \phi) = \begin{pmatrix}
    -\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) \\ \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\ 
    \cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\ -\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $n(\theta, \phi)$ is the normal vector at $(\theta, \phi)$ of the surface defined by $p$ (see the paper).

Now, define
$$
s(\theta, \phi, \psi) = 
  \cos(\psi)p(\theta, \phi) + \sin(\psi)n(\theta, \phi).
$$
Then I observed the following fact. Fix a value of $\theta \in [0, \pi[$,
$\theta \neq \pi/2$, and take the function $s_\theta$ which associates $(\phi, \psi) \in [0, 2\pi[ \times [0, \pi[$ to the usual stereographic projection of $s(\theta, \phi, \psi)$.
Then $s_\theta$ is a parameterization of a ring Dupin cyclide. Why is it true? Is it a conformal parameterization? (I think $p$ is conformal and then $s_\theta$ is conformal, but I don't master this topic).

Moreover, I observed that for a fixed $\psi$, the curve $\phi \mapsto s_\theta(\phi, \psi)$ looks like a Villarceau circle of the cyclide. Is it really a Villarceau circle and why?

Here is a picture. The Villarceau circles are the boundaries of the blue and yellow ribbons.

[image]